# Otimização de Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Poderiam me ajudar a encontrar um meio de otimizar a formula abaixo? A planilha tem mais de 125 mil linhas com essa formula em umas 4 colunas e está gerando muita lentidão para processar as informações e até mesmo para abri-la.

```
=SE(
    $D125883="Receita";
    SEERRO(
        SEERRO(
            PROCV(
                $C125883;
                'X:\(Caminho Arquivo)\[Ago.15 a Jan.18.xlsx]%Venc'!$B$5:$AK$1048576;CB$1;FALSO
            )*$R125883;
                SE(
                    PROCV(
                        $J125883;
                        'X:\(Caminho Arquivo)\[Ago.15 a Jan.18.xlsx]%Venc_Cliente'!$H$4:$J$1048576;3;FALSO
                    )=CB$2;$R125883;0
                )
        );
        'X:\(Caminho Arquivo)\[Ago.15 a Jan.18.xlsx]%Venc'!AF$9454*$R125883
    );
    SE(
        SEERRO(
            PROCV(
                $J125883;
                'X:\(Caminho Arquivo)\[Ago.15 a Jan.18.xlsx]%Venc_Cliente'!$H$4:$J$1048576;3;FALSO
            );
            'X:\(Caminho Arquivo)\[Ago.15 a Jan.18.xlsx]%Venc_Cliente'!$F$2
        )=CB$2;$R125883;0
    )
)
```

Agradeço pela ajuda desde já.

Comment: Ou você reprograma a planilha em VBA com as formas otimizadas de realizá-las. Ou desabilita o cálculo automático das células e só habilita em determinada hora do dia, por exemplo: no almoço ou depois de realizar as alterações. E depois desabilita de novo. São muitas linhas com cálculo automático em cada célula e com interação com outras planilhas.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação @danieltakeshi!!